# PHP Call to undeclared function. I'm sure I've declared it

Tags: php

I've declared the below functions in a file named global.php

```
function db_quote($value) {
    $connection = db_connect();
    return "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value) . "'";
}

function db_connect() {

    // Define connection as a static variable, to avoid connecting more than once 
    static $connection;

    // Try and connect to the database, if a connection has not been     established yet
    if(!isset($connection)) {
        // Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of     your configuration file
        $config = parse_ini_file('../../config.ini'); 
        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
    }

    // If connection was not successful, handle the error
    if($connection === false) {
        // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
        return mysqli_connect_error(); 
    }
    return $connection;
}
```

In login.php my code starts like this

```
require_once('/global.php');

db_connect();

    $u = db_quote($_POST['username']);
    $p = db_quote($_POST['password']);
```

I get no errors with the db_connect function, however trying to use db_quote gives Call to undefined function. Surely both or neither should be undefined?

Can anyone suggest why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: is global.php and login.php in the same directory ? if yes then remove the / from /global,php

Comment: Remove the slash if the files are on the same directory level

Comment: Surely there would be an error with calling db_connect() as well if global.php wasn't being included correctly? Changed the file path and the error with db_quote() remains

Comment: manually set function param and test it once

Comment: @FerozAkbar - You mean replace $_POST['username'] with a string? Tried that but no difference

Comment: why are you calling db_connect 2 times, in login.php and in  db_quote function, just use the $connection in db_quote funcion by declaring it as global $connection;

Answer (score 0):

Changing from require_once(global.php) to include(global.php) has fixed it. Thanks for the suggestions.